# Fill html select using javascript array

Tags: javascript, html

I want to fill a select with and array values. I don't see why my code doesnt work. I am a beginner.This is my script

```
    var mes = new Array();
for(i = 0; i < 12; i++){
    mes[i] = i;
}

var sel = document.getElementById('mes');
for(var i = 0; i < mes.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = mes[i];
    opt.value = mes[i];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}
```

And this is the html select:

```
<select name="mes" id="mes"></select>
```

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/kz1jnhzp/ - is the script after your HTML has loaded?

Comment: Actually, that works fine.. Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/74ykmmgd/

Comment: Look at the JavaScript console in your developer tools. It will probably give you a useful error message.

Comment: @tymeJV the script is in the head, it works on JSfiddle but when i load it up on dreamweaver presing f12, it doesnt work, its wierd.

Comment: @PabloMatíasGomez Gracias ;)

Comment: @Quentin Is says: TypeError: sel is null

Comment: @Veslor Then you should use onReady or maybe put the code at the bottom of the html.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632137/why-is-document-getelementbyid-returning-null)

Comment: @PabloMatíasGomez Yeah I just realize that _'mes'_ doesnt exist when the script is running. Is there any way to put the script in the head and be able to access the _'mes'_ ID

Comment: @Veslor yes, using a dom ready function. You could try jquery and then use `$(function() { ...code here.. });`

Comment: @PabloMatíasGomez Thx, ive already done it with "window.onload". But thx anyway ;)